# Deploying Flask app on Heroku - web1:crashed

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am trying to deploy a Flask app to Heroku , but I recieve this error:

```
(venv)rgb:~/flaskapp/app$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `gunicorn app:app`
web.1: crashed 2014/07/09 21:39:45 (~ 10s ago)
```

It works locally with 'foreman start' but pushing it on Heroku the web crashes:

```
(venv)rgb@rgb-K45VD:~/flaskapp/app$ foreman start 
21:41:01 web.1  | started with pid 3269
```

This is the following heroku logs:
(venv)rgb@rgb-K45VD:~/flaskapp/app$ heroku logs

```
2014-07-09T18:38:42.934053+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by user
2014-07-09T18:38:42.934053+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by user
2014-07-09T18:38:57+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-07-09T18:39:31+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-07-09T18:39:30.976889+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by user
2014-07-09T18:39:31.123082+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ea4c116 by user
2014-07-09T18:39:31.123204+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by user
2014-07-09T18:39:35.095809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2014-07-09T18:39:38.231874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-07-09T18:39:38.232507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-07-09T18:39:38.229063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-07-09T18:39:42.092210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2014-07-09T18:39:44.747854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-09T18:39:46.210641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-07-09T18:39:46.180463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2014-07-09T18:39:50.025372+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by user
2014-07-09T18:41:30.849878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=flazkeh.herokuapp.com request_id=89f286f6-44ec-4751-91ec-7411857fbd80 fwd="80.223.191.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-09T18:41:31.434515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=flazkeh.herokuapp.com request_id=63c33396-87d9-4b33-89a5-3f2288b707cd fwd="80.223.191.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This seems to be the error:

```
2014-07-09T18:41:30.849878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=flazkeh.herokuapp.com request_id=89f286f6-44ec-4751-91ec-7411857fbd80 fwd="80.223.191.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-07-09T18:41:31.434515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=flazkeh.herokuapp.com request_id=63c33396-87d9-4b33-89a5-3f2288b707cd fwd="80.223.191.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code superficially, I don't see anything wrong with it. Did you try running it on your own machine?

By the way, there are some things in the code that caused it not to run on my machine:

- there needs to be an environment variable "APP_SETTINGS" (did you set it?)
- there needs to be a models.py module - probably containing the BlogPost class. Seems there's no such file on GitHub?
- did you install flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: Please don't ask me to check out your entire project and debug it for you.. what did you try to find out where the bug is?

Comment: By the way: there are merge conflicts (which will cause syntax errors) in multiple files in your repo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you changed your procfile from **web: gunicorn app:app** to **web: gunicorn project:app**.
Also once you deploy to heroku you will have issues with the db. Best bet is to "DROP" the database and create a new one or migrate.
Use the command **heroku logs** to get more info.